# Snapshot in Openbravo

Tags: postgresql, openbravo

What exactly creating  snapshot means in openbravo. How to create and restore it.I am new to openbravo and i dont have any idea about it.
I have ubuntu OS  running on my machine with openbravo 3 and  postgresql 8.4 database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: So are you asking 2 questions? 1) What does creating a snapshot mean? and 2) How do I create and restore one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a newbie developing with Openbravo framework, you have an instance up and running, and you want to start testing something. Making an snapshot of your current state, gives you a easy way to step back if something goes wrong .

snapshot actually creates the database dump and also creates backup of your openbravo source folder using ant script.

You can manually create database dump by right clicking on the database and selecting **backup** option ,and doing the same for the openbravo source folder.

Follow these steps to create a snapshot ..

step1: Get the snapshot script code from  [here](http://bitbucket.org/iperdomo/labs/raw/8db9dcb650d3/openbravo/snapshot.xml#sthash.DYOpnnd5.dpuf) . copy the code and save it as snapshot.xml

step2:go to your openbravo source folder lets say for ex

cd  /home/openbravo(your openbravo instance folder)

enter the following command  to create snapshot   **ant -f snapshot.xml**

In order to restore it enter the following command  **ant -f snapshot.xml restore**

check the link for more information
[creating snapshot in openbravo](http://planet.openbravo.com/blog/making-an-snapshot-of-your-openbravo-instance/)

Comment: I did not get the step 1 , where do i have to save the snapshot.xml file?

Comment: Save it in openbravo source folder. Please go through the link .